# Pip does install although reporting conflicts

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to prevent installing two packages that conflict. But when I do:

```
pip install some-package
pip install another-package
```

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> some-package requires numpy==1.24.2, but you have numpy 1.24.3 which is incompatible.

> Successfully installed numpy-1.24.3 botocore-1.29.140 ... another-package

Now I am surprised I can import both `some-package` as `another-package` - shouldn't the second installation fail?

`pip check` does show the conflict.

> some-package has requirement numpy==1.24.2, but you have numpy 1.24.3.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) which suggests that it should be solved, but I am using pip 23.1.2.

Comment: Its possible that the package is over-constrained, or that there will be runtime failures due to assumption on version. As pip reported, it "does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed". The last package to be installed wins in terms of constraints. I recommenced only ever performing `pip install` once per virtual environment to avoid such issues. I believe if you did `pip install some-package another-package` as a single execution, it would fail as expected.